# How to switch to child window of a child window in Selenium(Window handles and titles are dynamic)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, window, handle

In one application, there is a child window, which opens another window. In total there are three windows. The window handles and the titles of each window are dynamic, they change every session.

So I stored the handles of the parent window and the first child window, then I called getWindowHandles method, stored all handles in a set, removed parent window and first child window. The remaining window handle in the set will be the third window handle.

```
Set<String> windowHandles = uiDriver().getDriver().getWindowHandles();
windowHandles.remove(parentHandle);
windowHandles.remove(firstChildHanlde);
String thirdChildHandle = windowHandles.toString();
```

It would be of great help if you can help me on how to get the child window handle in a more convenient way.

Comment: What's wrong with the way you've done it?

Comment: You could also keep track of handles with your own arraylist and use contains() to add new handles when iterating through the set.  If your array does not contain it, you add it.

Comment: @JeffC my code won't work if in case four windows open

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks for the suggestion, having an array list is more convenient as I could store the handles in order and get a specific handle using the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more generic method of handling windows handles you can get the `Set` of windows handles before you perform some action that opens more windows, perform the action, then get the `Set` of window handles afterwards, and then remove the "before" `Set` from the "after" `Set`. What remains are the windows that were opened during the action.

```
Set<String> beforeWindowHandles = uiDriver().getDriver().getWindowHandles();
// do something that opens a window
Set<String> afterWindowHandles = uiDriver().getDriver().getWindowHandles();
afterWindowHandles.removeAll(beforeWindowHandles);
```

Now `afterWindowHandles` contains only the newly opened windows.